# Как сделать чтобы при клике на кнопку менялся класс нижнего div?

Tags: jquery

Сделал чтото типо аккордеона, как сделать чтобы при клике на кнопку менялся класс нижнего див? на active и убирался при повторном клике?

```
<div class="myaccordeon">
<button class="accordion activeac">Сколько стоит вывоз строительного мусора за МКАД?</button>
<div class="panel" style="max-height: 84px;">
  <p>Строительство и ремонт сопровождаются образованием большого количества мусора, который требует транспортировки на специально предназначенные территории. 
Оптимальное решение в подобных условиях — заказ специализированного транспорта для вывоза строительного мусора.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Сколько стоит вывоз мусора с дачи?</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Строительство и ремонт сопровождаются образованием большого количества мусора, который требует транспортировки на специально предназначенные территории. 
Оптимальное решение в подобных условиях — заказ специализированного транспорта для вывоза строительного мусора.</p></div>

<button class="accordion">В чем преимущество вывоза мусора компанией “Мусор-РИН”?</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Строительство и ремонт сопровождаются образованием большого количества мусора, который требует транспортировки на специально предназначенные территории. 
Оптимальное решение в подобных условиях — заказ специализированного транспорта для вывоза строительного мусора.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Зачем вывозить мусор?</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Строительство и ремонт сопровождаются образованием большого количества мусора, который требует транспортировки на специально предназначенные территории. 
Оптимальное решение в подобных условиях — заказ специализированного транспорта для вывоза строительного мусора.</p>
</div>
</div>
<script>  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("activeac");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал max-height:100% и все нормально

Answer (score 0):

Вообще в jQuery для этого есть метод .toggleClass()